# Unexpected output with arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Web::Scraper;
use Data::Dumper;
use URI;
my $purlToScrape='http://www.natboard.edu.in/dnbfinal.php';
my $webdata = scraper {      
      process 'td.noticeboard', "data[]" => 'TEXT';      
  };
my $dnbnotices = $webdata->scrape(URI->new($purlToScrape));
my @noticeboard=$dnbnotices->{data};
print ref @noticeboard."\n\n";
print Dumper(@noticeboard);
print scalar @noticeboard."\n";
for my $notice ( @noticeboard ) {
    if ($notice) {
        print $notice."\n";
    }    
}
print $noticeboard[1];
```

Output:

```
 $VAR1 = [
           'December - 2016 ',
           'DNB Final December -2016',
           '30th September, 2016',
           '',
           '',
           'JUNE - 2016 ',
           'DNB Final JUNE -2016',
           '15th May, 2016',
           '',
           '',
           'Dec - 2015 ',
           'DNB Final Dec -2015',
           '9th October, 2015',
           '',
           '',
           'June - 2015 ',
           'DNB Final June -2015',
           '6th May, 2015',
           '',
           '',
           'December - 2014 ',
           'DNB Final December - 2014',
           '30th September, 2014',
           '',
           ''
         ];
 1
 ARRAY(0x4521bd8)
 Use of uninitialized value in print at ./test1.pl line 21.
```

Questions:

1. Why is the ref not printing out "ARRAY"?
2. Why is the array count shown as 1? It's not a single element array.
3. Why are the elements of the array not being printed out?
4. Why is `$noticeboard[1]` uninitialized?

Comment: If you want to dump a hash or array, use `Dumper(\%hash)` or `Dumper(\@array)`. It's too confusing otherwise, as you've found out (since your array truly does have only one element, a reference to another array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- [`ref`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) returns an empty string when called on something else than a ref. So when doing `ref @xxx`, you can't expect anything else than an empty string.
Furthermore, `ref @noticeboard."\n\n"` is the same as `ref ((scalar @noticeboard)."\n\n")`, which is `ref "1\n\n"`, which returns an empty string.

2-3-4- [`scrape`](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Web-Scraper-0.38/lib/Web/Scraper.pm#scrape) returned you an array reference, not an array. So when assigning it to an array (`my @noticeboard=$dnbnotices->{data}`), it went in the first element. (the fact that the array only has one element that is an array ref explains your question 2, 3 and 4).

Your script should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Web::Scraper;
use Data::Dumper;
use URI;
my $purlToScrape='http://www.natboard.edu.in/dnbfinal.php';
my $webdata = scraper {      
      process 'td.noticeboard', "data[]" => 'TEXT';      
  };
my $dnbnotices = $webdata->scrape(URI->new($purlToScrape));
my $noticeboard=$dnbnotices->{data};
print "ref=",ref($noticeboard),"\n\n";
print "dumper:",Dumper($noticeboard);
print "nb elements:",scalar @$noticeboard,"\n";
print "content:\n";
for my $notice ( @$noticeboard ) {
    if ($notice) {
        print "  ",$notice,"\n";
    }    
}
print "first element:",$noticeboard->[1];
```

Also, feel free to use [`say`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) instead of `print ... "\n"`, it can be more convenient. (you'll need `use feature 'say'` or `use v5.10` or higher though).

If you need further references about references, see [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).